# Grouping on specific condition

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling to achieve a record set where I want to group rows.

Column TRXCODE with value (8202) contains 10% value in TRAMT column so we have to find which TRAMT's value this 10% is then we have to group those 2 columns.

As per my image I want a new column(Groupid) to mark them a number to identify as a group.

Numbers in Groupid are just for example these could any number but same for 1 group.

[image]

Script

```
CREATE TABLE #TempRecords 
    (CODE VARCHAR(20), TRDATE DATE, TRBATCH INT, TRREF VARCHAR(20), TRXCODE INT, TRAMT decimal(8,2)
);

GO

INSERT INTO #TempRecords
 VALUES ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 1753, 31.20),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 8202, 3.12),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-21', 6957, 'SD21010304', 8104, 589.68),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8104, -31.20),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 1753, -589.68),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8202, -3.12),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8104, 554.60),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 1753, 32.18),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-01-30', 7024, '0000056246', 8202, 3.22),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-03-07', 7301, '0000057577', 1001, 1250.00),
        ('ABMSC31', '2003-09-25', 8737, '0000060259', 1701, 1104.00)

GO

SELECT * FROM #TempRecords
```

Comment: How is group with `groupId=10` grouped?

Comment: I just added a example like using Rank function to mark these rows with some numbers - Green marked rows are a group where TRXCODE IS 8202 with value 10% and the other adjacent green that 10% is of this row.

Comment: Do you have to group a row with `TRXCODE=8202` with  rows having any other `TRXCODE` having `TRAMT=10% of that at 8202`?

Comment: Yes Ajay, I have to group 8202 row which contains 10% value and other row based 10% value is - In the image I attached row 1,2 would be one group and row 4,5 and row 6,7 these all relates to TRXCODE  8202 - Remaining rows which does not fall in TRXCODE 8202 would also have it own group like row 13, 14, 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Declare @tbl table  (CODE VARCHAR(20), TRDATE DATE, TRBATCH INT, TRREF VARCHAR(20), TRXCODE INT, TRAMT decimal(8,2), TRAMT1 decimal(8,2))

Insert into @tbl 
Select *,null FROM #TempRecords

Update @tbl Set TRAMT1 = TRAMT where TRXCODE=8202
Update @tbl Set TRAMT1 = 0.1*TRAMT where TRXCODE<>8202

Select Code, TRDATE,TRBATCH, TRREF,TRXCODE,TRAMT, DENSE_RANK () OVER(ORDER BY TRAMT1) as groupID  from @tbl order by TRAMT1
```

Comment: Brilliant Ajay are awesome! - Thanks a lot for your help I will modify it a bit according to my needs. Cheers

Comment: Ajay using your idea I have simplified query as below - SELECT *,DENSE_RANK () OVER(ORDER BY TRAMT1) as groupID 
   FROM(
        SELECT CODE,
               TRDATE,
               TRBATCH,
               TRREF,
               TRXCODE,
               TRAMT,
               CAST(IIF(TRXCODE = 8202, TRAMT, TRAMT * 0.10 ) AS DECIMAL(8,2))  AS TRAMT1
         FROM  #TempRecords 
         ) AS RecSet
          ORDER BY TRAMT1